# Run JQuery after Specific updatePanel fires

Tags: jquery, .net, updatepanel

I have a script that runs once an update panel fires:
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        initDropSearch();
    }
    function initDropSearch() {

```
    var search = jQuery("#searchBar div.productSearchFilter");

    if (search.length > 0) {

        var grid = search.find("table.gridView");

        if (search.next().val() != "open") {

            search.animate({
                height: ['toggle', 'easeOutBounce'],
                opacity: 'toggle'
            }, 1000)

            .next().val("open");

        } else {

            search.show();

        }
    }
}
```

Once the results of a search have loaded, the container drops down and bounces.

It works perfectly - that is until another update panel is triggered on the same page - in which case the search panel opens again.

What I need to do is only run the script when a specific updatePanel fires.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the `sender` or `args` contain data about the UpdatePanel that triggered the `EndRequestHandler`?

If so just check which one triggered it and only fire your code based on that.

```
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    if (((UpdatePanel)sender).ID == "UpdatePanel1") {
        initDropSearch(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that code presented by @Chris is javascript. So type casting is not available. But I think that the rest of your answer is correct and one of these objects has information about UpdatePanel which triggered the event.